Program suddenly started crashing with ntdll.dll access violation
I was playing CoreKeeper 0.7.5.2a without any issues, never crashed, then suddenly after a PC restart the game crashes at start up no matter what. I was fiddling with drivers and updated powershell before restarting. I used WinDBG and Process Monitor to see what happens.
x64dbg log file: https://www.mediafire.com/file/md1i3or9zab00qr/core.txt/file
WinDBG:
Loading unloaded module list
.
This dump file has an exception of interest stored in it.
The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
(b1c.908): Access violation - code c0000005 (first/second chance not available)
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for ntdll.dll
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for ntdll.dll -
ntdll!NtDelayExecution+0xa:
00000000`779d9bca c3              ret
It mentions an access violation for ntdll.dll, it exists and other programs are using it if I check it with Unlocker. I didnt fiddle with ntdll.
Process Monitor reports(csv and pml):
https://file.io/CHssKQJf47KT
This one mentions a lot of dlls as "name not found".
Ntdll.dll included.
I have tried:
Restarting ,using safe mode, sfc scannow,disabling antivirus before running the game, checking if ntdll is not corrupt ,run as admin,compat mode,deleting 2 crash-handling exes of the game, deleting apdata files,reinstalling,redownloading,reinstaling redistributables.

You were "fiddling with drivers": can you be more clear about what sort of fiddling you were doing prior to restarting your computer and then this game failing?

I used DISM++ to install some LG android phone drivers, some portable device drivers and 2 other related to usb storage and phones in general, nothing to do with ntdll, and those 4 driver installs failed so I just closed DISM++. I didnt think it mattered so I didnt write it in the OP. I also updated Powershell.

@theo1996 - Try uninstalling those drivers. The analysis WinDBG has generated is basically extremely generic; it does not contain any information to diagnose the problem, which suggests the problem is system file integrity.

The problem likely isn't ntdll.dll, the checksum issue is a red herring: explanation

@Ramhound they didnt install in the first place but failed. What can I do if this is not a ntdll issue?How can I find out why its crashing? any other ideas why it might be crashing?

I don’t know; Your diagnostic tools on Windows 7 are non-existent

See https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-fix-ntdll-dll-errors-2624474 for some things to try. That said, it might be necessary to completely uninstall CoreKeeper, removing all data from drive and Registry, then reinstalling the game.

I added a x64dbg log file. https://www.mediafire.com/file/md1i3or9zab00qr/core.txt/file I can see it loads the dlls.
